# Cannot find items array in GA4 realtime analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a google analytics account that is connected to my application with google tag manager. Here I have added `begin_checkout` event results in both debug view and realtime analytics. In my debug view, I can see the items array with all the item data but that items array won't show up in the realtime analytics. Can someone please explain the reason for this and way to fix it?

I have added screenshots of the debug view and realtime analytics below.

**Debug View Output**

[image]

**Realtime Analytics**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the realtime reporting view you will only see event parameters. Because the items parameter is an array, it will not show up in the realtime report. This is not supported by the realtime view; you can debug it in the debug view as you already did.

Comment: Is there anyway that I can view all the item arrays that belongs to every checkout event?

Comment: You could use the explorations report in GA4. Add "Event Name" as dimension and filter this dimension by your events, e.g. "begin_checkout". Then you can add corresponding dimensions from items array to the report.